# Cyclic inequality with factorials exponent

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, exponentiation

I was wondering myself about an inequality found on a maths website (but unfortunately now deleted ):

> Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $a+b+c=1$ then we have :
>   $$3(\frac{1}{3})^{(\frac{1}{3})!}\geq a^{b!}+b^{c!}+c^{a!}\geq 1$$
>   I have spent a lot of time on this inequality and first my idea was to make symmetry because we have : 
>   $$2(\frac{a+b}{2})^{(\frac{a+b}{2})!}\geq a^{b!}+b^{a!}$$
>   To be true this last inequality needs the condition of the beginning ($a+b+c=1$).
>   So it delete the cyclicity .
>   Secondly my idea was to use the Jensen's  inequality but the function $x^{x!}$ is not concave between 0 and 1.
>   Maybe someone can achieve this.
>   Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Does “ because we have ...” mean that you *know* that the second inequality is true? Where is the proof?

Comment: How is defined $x!$ for $0<x<1$?

Comment: @AlexRavsky I don't know I create my inequality with Wolfram alpha wich gives values for $x!$ on the interval $0<x<1$